# Preloading default data into Core Data - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to make an app that uses preloaded data in Core Data.  The data is baseball stats from the last 100 years.  Anyways I created an entity and saved data in a previous version using the simulator.

Then I created a another app with the same name, same entity, and added the .sqlite file from the original app to the my new apps mainBundle. I updating the persistentStoreCoordinator method just as done in Apple's CoreDataBooksAppDelegate.m example, though nothing seems to be preloaded.  Why?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Master.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Test listing all Master data from the store
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Master" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (Master *master in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"first name: %@", master.nameFirst);
        NSLog(@"last name:  %@", master.nameLast);
        NSLog(@"debut:      %@", master.debut);
        NSLog(@"playerID:   %@\n\n", master.playerID);
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "steindorf.Baseball_Stats" in the application's documents directory.
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Baseball_Stats" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Baseball_Stats.sqlite"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]){
        NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Baseball_Stats" withExtension:@"sqlite"];

        if (defaultStoreURL) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultStoreURL toURL:storeURL error:NULL];
        }
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

@end
```

This is the data that gets saved in the original version though I can't get it to preload in my new app

```
2015-06-06 18:25:14.771 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] first name: Hank
2015-06-06 18:25:14.771 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] last name:  Aaron
2015-06-06 18:25:14.772 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] debut:      1954-04-13
2015-06-06 18:25:14.772 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] playerID:   aaronha01

2015-06-06 18:25:14.772 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] first name: George
2015-06-06 18:25:14.772 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] last name:  Brett
2015-06-06 18:25:14.773 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] debut:      1973-08-02
2015-06-06 18:25:14.773 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] playerID:   brettge01

2015-06-06 18:25:14.773 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] first name: Ty
2015-06-06 18:25:14.773 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] last name:  Cobb
2015-06-06 18:25:14.773 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] debut:      1905-08-30
2015-06-06 18:25:14.773 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] playerID:   cobbty01

2015-06-06 18:25:14.774 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] first name: Tony
2015-06-06 18:25:14.774 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] last name:  Gwynn
2015-06-06 18:25:14.774 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] debut:      1982-07-19
2015-06-06 18:25:14.774 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] playerID:   gwynnto01

2015-06-06 18:25:14.829 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] first name: Stan
2015-06-06 18:25:14.829 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] last name:  Musial
2015-06-06 18:25:14.829 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] debut:      1941-09-17
2015-06-06 18:25:14.830 Baseball Stats[12661:637413] playerID:   musiast01
```

[image]

I THINK THIS WILL WORK - does this approach seem appropriate

instead of preloading the data, make a NSFetchRequest when app lauches and if the array of managedObjects == 0, then begin to save all the data. This way all entity objects will get created and saved only the first time the app launches. And of course the bulk of the data will get created and saved dispatch_async so the user doesn't wait for everything to be loaded the first time

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSError *error;
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"miniMaster" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* MASTER = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                        error:&error];
    // Test listing all Baseball_Stats from the store
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Master" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)[fetchedObjects count]);

    //if fetchRequest doesn't find any objects for selected entity, load and save data
    if([fetchedObjects count] == 0){
        for (id m in MASTER) {
            Master *master = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Master"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            master.nameFirst = [m objectForKey:@"nameFirst"];
            master.nameLast  = [m objectForKey:@"nameLast"];
            master.debut     = [m objectForKey:@"debut"];
            master.playerID  = [m objectForKey:@"playerID"];

            NSError *error;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
        fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }

    for (Master *master in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"first name: %@", master.nameFirst);
        NSLog(@"last name:  %@", master.nameLast);
        NSLog(@"debut:      %@", master.debut);
        NSLog(@"playerID:   %@\n\n", master.playerID);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why did you not use the same app to generate the initial data? I would assume that there is some metadata that leads to incompatibility of stores for separate bundles.

Comment: Do you get anything in `defaultStoreURL` ?

Comment: i this approach acceptable, make a NSFetchRequest when app lauches and if the array of managedObjects == 0, then save all the data.  This way all entity objects will get created and saved the first time the app launches, instead of preloading the data.  And of course the bulk of the data will get created and saved dispatch_async so the user doesn't wait for everything to be loaded the first time

Comment: @ntsh  what should I be checking in the defaultStoreURL.  The Baseball_Stats.sqlite file (/Users/jsteindorf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/527223BD-EB6A-4B69-8289-67F27D9DC0EE/data/Containers/Data/Application/BB5B615F-8293-4E9C-A718-A5D65D4EE4B6/Documents/Baseball_Stats.sqlite)is there but it's machine code, so I can't physically see what it is, though nothing seems to load so I assume it doesn't have any objects saved

Comment: You could use `sqlite3 Baseball_Stats.sqlite` command  in terminal to browse data using SQL commands. However, I was asking if your defaultStoreURL is Null, if you put the breakpoint in your code. If it's null, maybe you didn't check the `Copy Items if Needed` checkbox, while copying your database to your project. Also, your 2nd approach seems to be OK.

Comment: @ntsh thanks for hanging in there with me....                     Baseball_Stats.sqlite seems to be populated.......                                  sqlite> .open Baseball_Stats.sqlite
sqlite> select * from ZMASTER;
1|1|1|1954-04-13|Hank|Aaron|aaronha01
2|1|1|1973-08-02|George|Brett|brettge01
3|1|1|1905-08-30|Ty|Cobb|cobbty01
4|1|1|1982-07-19|Tony|Gwynn|gwynnto01
5|1|1|1941-09-17|Stan|Musial|musiast01
                     and i copied items if needed and added to target.  I guess I'll use my second approach but I'd still like to understand why I can't load my .sqlite as default data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you're copying the `.sqlite` file but not the journal files (the `wal` and `shm` files). With the default SQLite journal mode, most of the data will end up in the journal files. Make sure you get all of them.

Comment: I added the 2 files but still no luck, they don't NSLog as expected in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  I updated the image to show this